# InvalidCastException with DrawerLayout

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm getting an InvalidCastException when I inflate a DrawerLayout and try to reference it in an Activity. Here's the relevant code in OnCreate:

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.EditProject);
View view = FindViewById (Resource.Id.editscope_main_layout);
_drawerLayout = (Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout)view;
```

The type of the inflated view is android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout (lower case namespace).

Here's the stack trace:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
at MyProduct.MyActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle) [0x00040] in /Users/me/code/my.domain/MyProduct/EditProjectActivity.cs:71
at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00011] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-15/src/generated/Android.App.Activity.cs:1943
at at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.2b3da45b-0937-483d-861b-9eb3158d596a (intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00017, 0x00043>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you not using `FindViewById<T>` like:

```
_drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.editscope_main_layout);
```

If that does not work try:

```
_drawerLayout = FindViewById(Resource.Id.editscope_main_layout).JavaCast<DrawerLayout>();
```

The former works fine in one of my samples: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/DrawerSample/blob/master/DrawerSampleActivity.cs#L31

Comment: Not sure why the other cast syntax wouldn't work but delighted to find that this one does.

Comment: Has anyone managed to get the DrawerLayout working with Monodroid.Dialog in MvvmCross?